# how to fix a rig when weightpaints still dont work

Tags: rigging

hello I am working on this dragon and I used a plug-in for blender..well using this set of bones does work but it pulls in places that it shouldn't even after weight painting I was directed here even though the group I asked the same question in.. some how could not help me..here is a snapshot of it..i don't think it should pull in those places when I move that leg[image: rig trouble on dragon]

I have learned some of blender on my own the past two years so I really have had no help except watching video's on youtube so if you guys have any idea's id appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

May be you have hidden bones or bones in hidden layers?
If not, try to unmarks "Deform" for bones which you don't want to be deformers.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you've simply missed a couple of vertices while weight painting. Sometimes a bone that is quite far away from the vertex can still have influence over it for some reason or another. One thing I've found that can help is to switch to wireframe view while weight painting. In this view the colors are brighter and more uniform, so it's easier to see when something is slightly off.

A value only slightly above zero could be causing this problem, but would still appear quite blue. You could try weight painting while the rig is positioned in a way where you can see the bad deformation as well. Then all you have to do is select every bone that was moved and use the subtract brush (or whatever is appropriate to fix the issue) and paint over the affected area until you find the cause.